# Subject.error with asObservable causes Angular 6 async pipe to rapidly consume all system memory

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject

In Angular 6 I have a very simple component like so:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject ,  Subject ,  Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
    styleUrls:[]    
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit{

    someSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject("Hey");    

    ngOnInit(){
        this.someSubject.error("Some error.");
    }

    get observable():Observable<string>{
        return this.someSubject.asObservable();
    }

}
```

...and this template:

```
<div>
    Will it resolve?

    <div *ngIf="observable | async as value">
        Value: {{value}}
    </div>

</div>
```

When I run this I'd expect the error to be encountered, which would close the stream and simply not render (as if I had called `.complete`), but instead it rapidly outputs the error message to the console and will very quickly consume all 24GB of memory on my dev box.

Why is this the case?  Can it really be that if you allow an error to feed into the `async` pipe your punishment is total system memory depletion?

EDIT:

I see now it is the `asObservable` call causing this problem, as it is getting a new instance each time (although I'd still think it should not go back for more if the existing one is in error).  What's the right pattern to use if I only want to expose an `Observable` downstream without running into this?

Comment: Just do `return this.someSubject`. It's already an observable.

Comment: Yes, but then anyone downstream can call '.next' on it.  I'd rather that be restricted to the service and not available to any observers.

Comment: That's fine, but you take the observable that was created and store it somewhere. Don't call functions directly from templates where the values returned are always changing.

Comment: Right - in my comment below the accepted answer I mention that this is the logical result of this.  Just means I have to store it as well - in this simple example it is trivial but this has larger implications on my application as a whole which are more annoying.  I accept that is just how it is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change the `get` to `property`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject ,  Subject ,  Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
    styleUrls:[]    
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit{

    someSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject("Hey");    
    data$;

   ngOnInit(){
       this.data$ = this.someSubject.asObservable();
    }


}
```

template

```
<div>
    Will it resolve?

    <div *ngIf="data$| async as value">
        Value: {{value}}
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are right, but in my larger application where they contain the state of a rest resource I have to not only create a cache of the Subjects (for when I have to update them), but also a cache of observable versions of those Subjects (which I hand out to components from the related service).

I get it though.  Just annoying for me.  Wish there was a way to prevent the pipe from requesting new instances, but I see the bigger picture here - thanks.

Comment: @WillyC the pipe is not requesting new instances. The original example called a function which **always** returned a new instance. This has nothing to do with observables or pipes. Angular will get stuck in change detection if the value is always changing.

Comment: Yeah, but if the observable resolves to a value this works as expected in that it stops calling that.  I get it, I just wish it would also resolve it on an error, but it doesn't work that way - fair enough.